# MySQL - Move Comma Separated Values to new Table Column

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a row in a MySQL column named tags.

In tags I have a series of keywords separated by commas. For this example lets use ice cream as the theme.. mmmmmmm.... Ice Cream :).

So in my tags row I have:

```
Vanilla, Strawberry, Coconut, Chocolate, Rocky Road, etc.
```

I also have a column in the same table named Ice Cream Shop. Each with just one shop name and an id.

So the entire record in the the table will have:

Shop ID: 1
Shop Name: Yum Yum
Tags: Vanilla, Strawberry, Coconut, Chocolate, Rocky Road

Now here's the kicker.. in the table mentioned above there is more rows in the table which I need to keep where they are.

What I want to do is take the tags aspect and move it to a completely new table with only the info I want from the table.

So essentially I need to do this:

- Copy the following Data from the ID Row, Shop Row, and Tags row into a new table Title Ice Cream.

Then be able to take all tags within the tags row and put each tag in its own row with corresponding ID, etc.

So:

### Table_Name 1

```
ID | Shop    | Tags
---------------------
1  | Yum Yum | Vanila, Strawberry, Chocolate, Coconut
```

to

### New_Table (probably named tags)

```
ID | Tag        | Shop
------------------------------
1  | Vanila     | Yum Yum
2  | Strawberry | Yum Yum
3  | Chocolate  | Yum Yum
4  | Coconut    | Yum Yum
```

Is this possible? If so how can I go about doing this in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the discussion [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,235478,235478#msg-235478). It's about writing a stored procedure with the same purpose as yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
     SELECT shop,
     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag
               ORDER BY tag SEPARATOR ',')
     FROM Table
     GROUP BY shop;
```

Comment: This is the opposite of what the question is looking for